# Setting up Reserve Instance for Spot Instance AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My question is that of concern for the increasing unstable price hikes on the spot market. 
I have seen things go from mellow and safe feeling to times insane price hikes appear. I understood this was a possibility of spot but never to the extent it has reached.

So my question is something I haven't been able to find an answer to in the AWS documentation nor on the web. But if I was to purchase a reserve instance in the same zone as my spot instance would, if the price hiked above my bid push my server over to the reserve instance, or would I loose the server to termination?

I love the current prices of spot but if a price spike occurred I would not mind paying the reserve hr price as it is always almost lower then the spike amount.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change a server from spot to reserve pricing without terminating and bringing up a new server.

Spot pricing was never designed for running web servers, the fact that people use it for that purpose is largely why the prices now spike the way they do. Originally spot was introduced for processing queues or jobs which could be terminated and restarted when spot prices dropped to acceptable levels.